# Wrong parameter in Query ActionLink MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>            
        @Html.ActionLink(item.numberOfDocumentFiles.ToString(), "GetDocumentFiles","Documents", new { docId = item.documentId.ToString() } )            
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.saveDate)
    </td>
</tr>
}
```

I am assuming `@Html.ActionLink` to generate `http://sitelink/Documents/GetDocumentFiles/6`

but getting `http://sitelink/Documents/GetDocumentFiles/?Length=9`

What am i missing? Thank in advance for your help !

Comment: `@Html.ActionLink(item.numberOfDocumentFiles.ToString(), "GetDocumentFiles","Documents", new { docId = item.documentId }, null )` (add the last parameter - and you do not need `.ToString()` for the route value)

Comment: And the `?Length=9` is because there are 9 characters in "Documents"

Comment: @StephenMuecke, it worked :) ... wondering if you explain a bit about the last parameter "null" ... does it make the trick ?

Comment: You currently using [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.LinkExtensions.ActionLink%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.String,System.Object,System.Object%29) where the 3rd parameter is the route values. The method serializes your object, which is a `string` and the only property of `string` is `Length` so `Length=9` is added to the `RouteValueDictionary`

Comment: Thank you Stephen , much appreciated